# pd.Series(pred).value_counts() how to get the first column in dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I apply pd.Series(pred).value_counts() and get this output:

```
 0     2084
-1       15
 1       13
 3       10
 4        7
 6        4
 11       3
 8        3
 2        3
 9        2
 7        2
 5        2
 10       2
dtype: int64
```

When I create a list I get only the second column:

```
c_list=list(pd.Series(pred).value_counts()), Out:

[2084, 15, 13, 10, 7, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

How do I get ultimately a dataframe that looks like this including a new column for size% of total size?

```
df=
[class ,   size  ,relative_size]
     0     2084  , x%
    -1       15  , y%
     1       13  , etc.
     3       10
     4        7
     6        4
     11       3
     8        3
     2        3
     9        2
     7        2
     5        2
     10       2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very nearly there. Typing this in the blind as you didn't provide a sample input:

```
df = pd.Series(pred).value_counts().to_frame().reset_index()
df.columns = ['class', 'size']
df['relative_size'] = df['size'] / df['size'].sum()
```